# sum of numbers for a given column in a sqlite database

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to get the `sum` of similar items in my rows in `sqlite`.

For example, all the values of **x**,all the values for **y** and all the values for **z**. I know how to use the `WHERE` clause in my query but the problem with it is that it requires i compare the values to another parameter. For example a query like this:

```
select sum(number_column) from your_table where number_column = 'some_number'
```

From the above, i dont have `'some_number'` to compare to. So i need a way to add all the values for each similar rows, kind of like grouping them together.

[image]

So i would end up with something like:

```
x 25
y 24
z 16
```

Is this possible? Any suggestions are welcomed.

EDIT:
I tried this after Cristian's suggestion:

```js
 private void getSumOfGroupedTime() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_CREATED_AT_AM_PM + ",sum(quantity) as sum FROM " + TABLE_SALES
                + " GROUP BY " + KEY_CREATED_AT_AM_PM, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        double i = c.getDouble(0);
        Log.d("sum_values_", String.valueOf(i));
        c.close();
    }
But it returns 1 for the three similar items i added in which each of these items have 1 as quantity. I expected 3. I'm i doing it wrong?
```

Comment: what's the name of the column that holds the x,y,z ?

Comment: It's a date string column, KEY_CREATED_AT

Comment: take a look to my update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a table that has the following structure:

```
+----------------+--------+
| KEY_CREATED_AT | number |
+----------------+--------+
| a              |    132 |
| e              |    264 |
| f              |    142 |
| x              |    132 |
| y              |    122 |
| z              |    112 |
+----------------+--------+
```

In order to have the sum of these separate values you would use the clause `group by`

So the query would be like this:

```
SELECT KEY_CREATED_AT,sum(number) as sum FROM table_name

GROUP BY KEY_CREATED_AT
```

Example here: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eea30c/1/0)

```
private void getSumOfGroupedTime() {
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + KEY_CREATED_AT_AM_PM + ",sum(quantity) as sum FROM " + TABLE_SALES
            + " GROUP BY " + KEY_CREATED_AT_AM_PM, null);
   try {
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Double sum = c.getDouble(1);

            Log.d("Sum is: " + sum);
        }
   } finally {
      c.close();
   }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, i added my attempt on the edit above, see